# Clear input box in React after clicking the submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, input, react-hooks

I am currently trying to clear the input field every time I try to submit the form but the content won't disappear

```
export default function MainContent() {
    const [note, setNotes] = React.useState('')
    const { addToContainer } = React.useContext(notesContext)
    const useRef = React.useRef(null)
    function change(e) {
        const { value, name, id } = e.target
        setNotes(prevNote => {
            return {
                ...prevNote,
                [name] : value
            }    
        })
    }
    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()  
        addToContainer(note)
   }

    return (<div><div className="main">Here are your notes!</div>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}><textarea  name="notes" onChange={(e) => change(e)} id="notes" value={note.notes} />
        <button>Submit here</button>    
        </form>
    </div>)    
}
```

I have tried to `setNotes('')` when submitting it but that does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You could extend the `handleSubmit()` function to reset the `useState()`:

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addToContainer(note);    // Handle Form
    setNotes('');            // Reset notes
}

<form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)} ...>
```

---

Small demo based on your code:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [note, setNotes] = React.useState('')
    
    function change(e) {
        const { value, name, id } = e.target
        setNotes(prevNote => {
            return {
                ...prevNote,
                [name] : value
            }    
        })
    }
    
    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // addToContainer(note);                // Handle Form
        console.log('Submit: ', note)           // Demo handler
        setNotes({ notes: ''});                 // Reset notes
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="main">Here are your notes!</div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}><textarea  name="notes" onChange={(e) => change(e)} id="notes" value={note.notes} />
                <button>Submit here</button>    
            </form>
        </div>
    )    
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I've changed it as specified but the note state gets wiped completely. I needed that for a separate component. Isn't there a way to erase the value of the textarea input instead?

Comment: @aliboxer: *"the note state gets wiped completely"* - Is that not the goal? What else do you mean by "clear the input field" if not to reset the state value which populates that input field? *"I needed that for a separate component"* - How is that being demonstrated in the question? Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which encapsulates what you're actually trying to do? *"Isn't there a way to erase the value of the textarea input instead"* - That's exactly what this does. At the moment it sounds like you're asking if there's a way to set the state to `''` without setting the state to `''`.

Comment: @aliboxer: If you're referring to the `addToContainer()` operation then perhaps that operation should be re-imagined a bit anyway.  Sending the entire object to some external destination is probably just asking for state-mutation problems.  (That external destination may not properly treat the data as an immutable state object.)  Perhaps this is another reason to focus on the actual string value instead of wrapping it in a single-property object, which doesn't seem to otherwise have a point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not give an object to the value of `<textarea />`,
I mean that the value must be a string type.
You said that you tried `setNotes('')`, which didn't work at all, (Have you changed the value from `note.notes` to `note`),  I think the following code must be like that:

```
export default function MainContent() {
  const [note, setNote] = React.useState(''); // Change 'setNotes' to 'setNote'
  const { addToContainer } = React.useContext(notesContext);
  const useRef = React.useRef(null);

  function change(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setNote(value); // Set 'note' directly as a string
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addToContainer(note);

    // Clear the input field after submitting the form
    setNote(''); // Reset 'note' to an empty string
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main">Here are your notes!</div>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <textarea name="notes" onChange={(e) => change(e)} id="notes" value={note} />
        <button>Submit here</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There seems to be an inconsistency on whether `note` is *a string*:

```
const [note, setNotes] = React.useState('')
```

Or *an object*:

```
setNotes(prevNote => {
    return {
        ...prevNote,
        [name] : value
    }    
})
```

The markup expects an object (with a `notes` property):

```
<textarea name="notes" onChange={(e) => change(e)} id="notes" value={note.notes} />
```

This could very well cause confusion in the rendering of the form element because sometimes the value is `undefined` (whether initially or after setting state back to `''`, in both cases `note.notes` is `undefined`), which could be switching this back and forth from a controlled to uncontrolled form element.

At the very least, this should be consistent.  If the intent is to use an object, initialize it as such:

```
const [note, setNotes] = React.useState({notes:''});
```

And reset it by resetting that object:

```
setNotes({notes:''});
```

Example:

```js
function MainContent() {
  const [note, setNotes] = React.useState({ notes: "" });
  //const { addToContainer } = React.useContext(notesContext)
  //const useRef = React.useRef(null)
  function change(e) {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    setNotes((prevNote) => {
      return {
        ...prevNote,
        [name]: value
      };
    });
  }
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //addToContainer(note)
    setNotes({ notes: "" });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main">Here are your notes!</div>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <textarea
          name="notes"
          onChange={(e) => change(e)}
          id="notes"
          value={note.notes}
        />
        <button>Submit here</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainContent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

**Alternatively**, if you would rather just use a simple string instead of an object:

```js
function MainContent() {
  const [note, setNotes] = React.useState("");
  //const { addToContainer } = React.useContext(notesContext)
  //const useRef = React.useRef(null)
  function change(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setNotes(value);
  }
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //addToContainer(note)
    setNotes("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main">Here are your notes!</div>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <textarea
          name="notes"
          onChange={(e) => change(e)}
          id="notes"
          value={note}
        />
        <button>Submit here</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainContent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

The code used to update the state in the `change` function implies that the *intent* is to add other fields to the object, though the *name* of the object doesn't imply that at all.  But the point is to pick one or the other.

Comment: I tried both methods and it works. Unfortunately the 'addToContainer(note)' that you commented out is a function that is meant to pass down this state to another component and that get's erased too.

Comment: @aliboxer: I commented it out for this example because it's not defined in the [mcve] provided.  You don't need to comment it out in yours.